# testing if a method is called

Tags: laravel, testing, phpunit, mockery

I'm trying to figure out how to do a proper test about if a function is being called or not.

This function **busqueda** is defined within a controller **AnuncioController**, so I expect it being called when a user clicks on a search button which posts to **anuncios/busqueda**.

As far as I'm concerned, this might be done with mocks. This is what I've tried:

```
use \App\Http\Controllers;
class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{

   public function testBuscador()
   {
    $mock_buscador = Mockery::mock(\App\Http\Controllers\AnuncioController::class);
    $mock_buscador->shouldReceive('busqueda')->once()->andReturn(null);
    $this->visit('/')->submitForm('Buscar')->seePageIs('anuncios/busqueda');
   }

}
```

But the assert always fails, am I using mocks wrongly?

Error msg:

> PHPUnit 4.8.21 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
>
> ....E
>
> Time: 352 ms, Memory: 23.25Mb
>
> There was 1 error:
>
> 1) ExampleTest::testBuscador Mockery\Exception\InvalidCountException:
>   Method busqueda() from
>   Mockery_0_App_Http_Controllers_AnuncioController should be called 
>   exactly 1 times but called 0 times.
>
> /var/www/html/anuncios.com/vendor/mockery/mockery/library/Mockery/CountValidator/Exact.php:37
>   /var/www/html/anuncios.com/vendor/mockery/mockery/library/Mockery/Expectation.php:271
>   /var/www/html/anuncios.com/vendor/mockery/mockery/library/Mockery/ExpectationDirector.php:120
>   /var/www/html/anuncios.com/vendor/mockery/mockery/library/Mockery/Container.php:297
>   /var/www/html/anuncios.com/vendor/mockery/mockery/library/Mockery/Container.php:282
>   /var/www/html/anuncios.com/vendor/mockery/mockery/library/Mockery.php:142
>   /var/www/html/anuncios.com/tests/ExampleTest.php:19
>
> FAILURES! Tests: 5, Assertions: 27, Errors: 1.

Routes.php fragment:

```
Route::post('anuncios/busqueda', [
    'as' => 'anuncios/busqueda',
    'uses' => 'AnuncioController@busqueda',
]);
```

AnuncioController.php fragment:

```
public function busqueda(Request $request)
{...}
```

Comment: You might not need to mock the controller in this case, because if you see what is suppose to be on the page, you would know the controller is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create the mock object `$mock_buscador` without actually using it. It seems like you expect any instance of `App\Http\Controllers\AnuncioController` to be replaced with the mock but this is not the case. You need to replace the used controller instance with the `$mock_buscador` mock object.

Comment: Oh, so I've misunderstood mocks, ain't? So in this case, I can't do it. How would you check if a method is called?

Comment: I think the test that you are trying to write is not of much use. You are writing a functional test (click button => expect result). `seePageIs()` already tests that the URL is `anuncio/busqueda`. Testing additionally if the controller action is called is not adding value and too low level for a functional test. Test instead what *happens* (or what the user should see)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the full path to the controller.

```
use \App\Http\Controllers;
class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{

   public function testSearch()
   {
        $mock_search = Mockery::mock(\App\Http\Controllers\AnuncioController::class);
        // or if you aren't using php 5
        // $mock_search = Mockery::mock('\App\Http\Controllers\AnuncioController');
        $mock_search->shouldReceive('busqueda')->once()->andReturn(null); 
        $this->visit('/')->submitForm('Buscar')->seePageIs('anuncios/busqueda');

   }
}
```

## Edit

I would use Mockery for your controller. I would use it more for Facades. I would rewrite the test to test what you want to see on the page.

```
use \App\Http\Controllers;
class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{

   public function testSearch()
   {
        $this->visit('/')
          ->type('expected', 'search')
          ->submitForm('Buscar')
          ->seePageIs('anuncios/busqueda')->
          ->see('expected results');

   }
}
```

Comment: php5.6, so I've tried with `$mock_search = Mockery::mock(\App\Http\Controllers\AnuncioController::class);
`. Still fails :(

Comment: busqueda has an injection method: `public function busqueda(Request $request)`. Could be because of this that the mock is not linking to that function?

Comment: `Method busqueda() from Mockery_0_App_Http_Controllers_AnuncioController should be called exactly 1 times but called 0 times.` tells me that Mockery is seeing your controller. It just isn't being called. can you post your route to this controller.

Comment: I thought the same, but notice that if I comment the mock->shouldReceive, then the last assertion works. I update the post right now

Comment: I've seen your edits, as you can see, that's my last assertion. But I'm worried about why the mock is not working btw

Comment: I believe Mockery takes over the object and you want to use it when you don't want that mocked object to do whatever it is doing. So for example, you'd want to mock the Mail facade so it doesn't sent mail. If you successfully mocked your controller i would imagine the `seePageIs` would fail because it would never be called.